# Como fazer a detecção automática de um Captive Portal

Tags: linux, apache, shell-script, iptables

Eu estou fazendo um hotspot em um servidor com CentOS 6 e gostaria de fazer com que os celulares (android e iOS) reconhecessem automaticamente que precisam de autenticação assim que conectar na rede, para redirecionarem ao login.

No meu firewall eu tenho a regra:

```
iptables -t nat -A NET_DHCP -i eth1 -s 172.16.0.0/16 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 172.16.0.1:80
```

No apache (httpd.conf):

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ErrorDocument 400 /var/www/dhcpauth/index.php
        ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/dhcpauth/index.php
        ServerPath /var/www/dhcpauth
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dhcpauth/
        <Directory /var/www/dhcpauth>
            AllowOverride All
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.html
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Em outras respostas à perguntas similares eu encontrei o seguinte código, mas não funcionou da forma que usei:

```
<!--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WISPAccessGatewayParam xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.wballiance.net/wispr_2_0.xsd">
<Redirect>
<MessageType>100</MessageType>
<ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
<VersionHigh>2.0</VersionHigh>
<VersionLow>1.0</VersionLow>
<AccessProcedure>1.0</AccessProcedure>
<AccessLocation>Andrew Wippler is awesome</AccessLocation>
<LocationName>MyOpenAP</LocationName>
<LoginURL>http://hotspot.localnet/</LoginURL>
</Redirect>
</WISPAccessGatewayParam>
-->
```

O hostpot (login e liberação de acesso) funciona normalmente quando acessamos a página de login diretamente pelo dns ou ip, mas eu precisava que aparecesse aquela mensagem "Essa rede precisa de autenticação". Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde sei os SO's (Android, IOS, Windows, etc), possuem mecanismos que verificam se um determinado acesso está sendo redirecionado para um IP que não deveria, caso isso for verdade o SO apresenta um alerta recomendando Login na Rede, eu fiz isso em FreeBSD utilizando Packet Filter(pf), mas a lógica deve ser a mesma com `iptables`

```
rdr  on {$int_wireless} inet proto {tcp} from !<logados> to any port 443 -> 192.168.99.1 port 443
rdr  on {$int_wireless} inet proto {tcp} from !<logados> to any port 80 -> 192.168.99.1 port 80
```

Quando um equipamento ganha `IP` via `DHCP` na rede Wifi as duas regras acima entram em ação, se o IP não estiver cadastrado na tabela `logados` ele redireciona qualquer tentativa de acesso para qualquer IP/Endereço do planeta para a minha página de Login (192.168.99.1), quando o cliente se Loga na rede etas duas regras se tornam inválida para o cliente logado, portando estas duas regras são as responsáveis para que os SO's sejam capazes de mostrar uma mensagem de `Login`.

Comment: É apenas o redirecionamento? Por que eu fiz isso já é aparentemente tinha funcionado, por que quando do celular eu tentava abrir uma página qualquer no chorme ela era redirecionada para a página de login. Só que a mensagem em si nunca apareceu. Eu vou tentar novamente convertendo essas regras que você pôs para iptables. Obrigado

Comment: Sim é o firewall redirecionando tudo para porta 443 e 80 que faz com que a mensagem de login aparece no SO, o apache não tem nada haver com a história

Comment: Eu testei exatamente como você mencionou:
```iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING_DHCP -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80```
```iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING_DHCP -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 443```
Só que em vez de aparecer que a rede precisa de login. Aparece a mesagem que a rede parece estar indisponível. Embora o redirect tenha funcionado por que quando tento abrir uma página no navegar ele redireciona para a pagina de login.

Comment: Todo o resto está bloqueado correto? não pode ter nenhuma outra porta de saída aberta no firewall, tudo na rede wifi deve estar em block, só deve estar liberado o ip do seu apache e o redirecionamento da porta 80 e 443

Comment: Está sim, A politica padrão do meu firewall é DROP. Mesmo assim por garantia agora eu inclui um DROP no FORWARD para a rede do wifi. O único ACCEPT que tem é para o próprio servidor onde está o apache

Comment: Os clientes que se conectam no Wifi, estão se conectando em AP's ou Routers ? eu acho que só funciona direito em AP's...

Comment: Eu consegui resolver mas tem a ver com o Apache sim. Para resolução eu precisei por um redirect do apache com o código 302 para a tela de login. Apenas esse redirect indica aos aparelhos que é preciso fazer login. Mas obrigado pela ajuda